# Django reverse inline for admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the `User` class which is referenced by foreign key by the `Student` class, `Parent` class, and `Teacher` class.

```
class User():
   pass

class Parent():
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Student():
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Teacher():
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I would like to do a `UserInline` and have `ParentAdmin` `TeacherAdmin`, etc.

Of course,  DjangoAdmin requires that `User` be the one that has a ForeignKey to `Parent`, `Teacher`, `Student`, etc., however I was wondering if we could potentially somehow reverse it or structure it that I could just create a Student or Teacher while incorporating the `UserInline`